# Invoke node.js from Linux desktop menu

Tags: node.js, linux, bash, shell

This may be related to how Linux desktop menu items are invoked.

I have a script like this:

    `#!/bin/bash
    cd ~/mydir/
    node server.js`

which works fine when I run it inside a terminal shell, but when I put it into the Linux desktop menu, the server was not executed (the process 'node' is not present).

I changed it to:

   `node ~/mydir/server.js`

but it is still not working (but it works in the shell terminal).

Strangely, when I was using other non-Node.js servers, such as `http-server`, it works even when the script is invoked from the desktop menu.

Any ideas?

Comment: What's the output when you do  node ~/mydir/server.js

Comment: "Server running at 127.0.0.1... etc" , it runs correctly even if I invoke node within a script, and the script is run from a bash terminal.  It fails when this very same script is invoked from the desktop menu.

Comment: Fails with what message?

Comment: Can't tell, it's behind the scenes, I use `ps` to check if node is running, and it's not (when invoked from desktop menu).  I included a beep sound in the server.js code, and the beep didn't sound either.